# Synonyms for "extra-"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, prefixes, affixes

I'm looking for prefixes similar to *extra-* in the sense of 'outside of'. I'm attaching it to "mathematical" and in its context "extra-mathematical" or "extramathematical" can be misread as "very mathematical".

I'm specifically trying to avoid "nonmathematical" because I want to stress the connections with, rather than differences from, that field.

The term would be used to refer to fields of study aside from math, e.g. chemistry or engineering.

---

*I'm tempted to add a [single-affix-requests] tag for this question... that would be wrong in so many ways.*

Comment: I think "fields related to math" or "fields other than math" would be the clearest way to state this. Or you could say something like *interdisciplinary studies of math and science.*

Comment: @JLG: A single word or affix would be best for this purpose, since I want to use this as a label (though I will use words to that effect in describing it). But _interdisciplinary_ is good, you should submit that as an answer.

Comment: What about defining your term? Use *extramathematical* and state what you mean by it the first time you do so.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a sentence that would convey the meaning you want, I think that would make it easier to come up with something suitable.

Comment: As I wrote above, I need a label. It will have a definition but I expect most will skim and miss it.

Comment: @FraserOrr: As I said it will be used as a label. An example of a thing which might be so labeled: https://oeis.org/A005960.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly a "neologism", since there are [10s of 1000s](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22quasi%20mathematical%22&oq=%22quasi%20mathematical%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.1171&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of prior instances on Google, but...
[quasi-mathematical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quasi-)
...is the term native speakers would coin on the spot even if they'd never come across it before.

In such contexts, *quasi-* is a [productive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_%28linguistics%29) prefix meaning *partially, akin to*. It's similar to [pseudo-](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pseudo), except that has more negative connotations of *counterfeit, false*.

---

You wouldn't normally refer to things like chemistry and engineering as *quasi-mathematical*, because these are disciplines in their own right, not examples of "mathematics manqué". But from some perspectives (not just mathematicians'!) mathematics doesn't only underpin all other disciplines - it actually *is* [the whole universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis). So I think OP would be quite justified in using *quasi-* for his particular context (maybe not so much if his starting point had been any other discipline!).

Answer (score 3):

What about "para-"?

> 1 beside; adjacent to: parameter | parataxis | parathyroid.
>
> • Medicine denoting a disordered function or faculty: paresthesia.
>
> • distinct from, but analogous to: paramilitary | paraphrase | paratyphoid.
>
> • beyond: paradox | paranormal | parapsychology.
>
> • subsidiary; assisting: paramedic | paraprofessional.

I'm thinking in the "beyond" sense.

Comment: I had considered it (in fact before I posted here I Googled [para extra non prefix] in hopes of a quick answer), but I use "paramathematical" very differently: things 'alongside' math but outside of it, like discussing what things are appropriate for a journal article. Still, a better answer may not exist...

Comment: I believe *para-* attached to a science usually means "besides" as in "besides *proper* science", almost like *pseudo-*, so not something so respectable as chemistry in the original question.

Comment: What @Cerberus said. I know there are neutral/positive examples in other spheres, but *specifically in relation to "hard" sciences*, **para-** is invariably "sneeringly negative".

Comment: @Cerberus and FumbleFingers, I am a professional scientist and I had never heard of paraphysics or parachemstry until I searched for them just now. It looks like only a handful of weirdos use the terms, but I agree that they have ruined them for other uses.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens: In this case, your ignorance is to your credit! (As in, you're not *supposed* to know of such silly pursuits.)

Answer (score 3):

[> **Supra**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/supra-)

a prefix meaning “above, over” (supraorbital)  or “beyond the limits of, outside of” 
(supramolecular; suprasegmental).

From which we get [*Supramathematical*](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=supramathematical&oq=supramathematical&gs_l=hp.12...18980.18980.2.20284.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.IZ-MJQ2LOMA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.bmk&fp=e4b9e1d505f544c2&biw=1680&bih=886), *suprachemical*, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Might **co-**, **semi-** or **demi-** work for this purpose?

Comment: _Comathematical_ doesn't quite seem to do it, but _semimathematical_ might (as long as one doesn't mind aggravating language purists).

Answer (score 0):

When I read the first sentence of your question, I immediately thought of “super-”, as in “supernatural.”  But, upon reading the rest of your question, I suggest “meta-”.  Or maybe “ultra-”, as in “ultra-violet.”

Comment: Unfortunately _metamathematics_ has acquired a technical meaning which would be distracting to my audience. _Ultramathematical_ is not a choice I would have considered but it might work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* is Greek, and the Greek equivalent of *extra-* is **exo-**, as in *exoskeleton* ("outside-skeleton"), *exotic* ("outside-ish"), *exogenous* ("outside-born"), exothermic ("outside-temperature-ish"), etc. The opposite is *endo-*. So *exomathematic* would be properly formed.

Comment: What I like best about this suggestion is that the term is almost entirely unused, a _tabula rasa_ for my audience.

Comment: @Charles: Your audience are tabulae rasae, and *exomathematical* is what you may inscribe onto them!